# Parallelizing over dimensions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization

I have a certain loss function `f` which works over 1D vectors. 
The data that I have is of dimension `nxd` , where `n` is the batch size and `d` is the dimension of the data.

I want to compute the loss function as the sum of `n` function calls of `f` each taking `d` values as the input.

The for loop version of the following looks like this -

```
# X_1 and X_2 are vectors of shape (d,n)
loss = 0
for i in range(n):
    loss += f(X_1[:,i],X_2[:,i])
```

The problem is that this takes a long time since `n` is large.
Is there a way to parallelize this over `n` in tensorflow 2.0 , i.e. have each of the `n` calls to `f` run in parallel (since they operate independently) ?

Comment: There is a `parallel_iteration` argument for `tf.map_fn`. You can fiddle around with that.

Comment: @thushv89 Hey, that actually worked out.
I used the following -
`tf.map_fn(lambda x:f(x[0],x[1]),(X,Y),dtype=tf.float32,parallel_iterations=1024)` , where `X` and `Y` have been transposed, and it is faster than the for loop implementation at least. However, there is virtually no difference in time of execution by tweaking the `parallel_iterations` parameter, and the overall implementation still seems to be pretty slow for my use case.

Comment: Assuming you are using TF 2.0, have you tried `@tf.function` by encapsulating `tf.map_fn` in a function?

Comment: Yes I did. `tf.map_fn` gave a warning about not being able to parallelize stuff without it. I believe that the best fix is to just vectorize `f` directly, though it may not be very feasible in some scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, `map_fn` is quite a party killer to be honest. I try to avoid it whenever I can. If it is possible to vectorize your `f` definitely go with that.